# How to update mongodb filed value into null without omitting it via mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am using flask-mongoengine and here is a problem confused me.
1. Models

```
class Student(Document):
    name = StingField()
    info = DictField(default={'address':None,'age':20},null=True)
```

2. update address

```
student = Student.objects(id=id).first()
student.info['address'] = 'LA'
student.save()
```

it works well

3. empty address

```
student = Student.objects(id=id).first()
student.info['address'] = None
student.save()
```

Here is the problem. The document in the collection omit the 'address' field.  It only show like this: info:{"age":20}.

Question:
How to keep the field exist in the collection even its value is null ?
(I know that using update instead of save can do this, but what if I insist using save, are ther any method to solve it?)